# Meteor app randomly returns an empty result from collection query

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a collection called `Application` that stores documents that has a property `user` that refers to the `userId`. This is how I associate a user to an application.

So to get the application of the currently logged in user, here is my code:

```
currentApp = function() {
    var userId = Meteor.userId(),
        appCursor = Applications.find({"user": userId});
    if (appCursor.count() === 0) {
        console.log('no application found');
        return ;
    } else if (appCursor.count() > 1){
        // when there are duplicate applications for a user
        console.log('apps found: ' + appCursor.count());
        return Applications.findOne({"user": userId});
    } else {
        // cursor fetch returns an array
       return appCursor.fetch()[0];
    }
}
```

This code works fine most of the times. However, once in a while, upon refreshing the page, I get the `no application found` error.

I am not sure why this is happening. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. If my question is not clear, feel free to ask for clarification!

UPDATE: once deployed to the server (meteor.com), if this error happens, it sticks. The only way to get things back to normal is to log out and log in again.

UPDATE: `currentApp` is used in a client template as follows

```
Template.form.app = function () {
    return currentApp();
}
```

Comment: When/how is `currentApp` getting called? It sounds like the subscription just isn't ready at the time of the call.

Comment: @DavidWeldon in a template, for eg `form`, I use it like this: `Template.form.app = function(){return currentApp();}`

Comment: If you are not using `autopublish`, what does your subscription to the applications collection look like? Also, please indicate if the subscription is inside a `Deps.autorun` call.

Comment: @DavidWeldon no I am not using `autopublish`. On the client template `js` file, where the `Template.form.app` is defined, I subscribe with this line: `Meteor.subscribe('applications');`. I am not sure what you meant by if it is inside a `Deps.autorun` call.